# Basic MVC View returns model properties as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

This is the setup:

Model:

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Manufactor Manufactor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
```

ControllerAction:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var devices = db.Devices.Include("Categories").Include("Manufactors").Select(x => new Device
                   {
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Category = x.Category,
                        Comments = x.Comments,
                        Manufactor = x.Manufactor,
                        Status = x.Status
                    });
    return View(db.Devices.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufactor.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The problem here is, that only name gets displayed, but `item.Category` and `item.Manufactor` not. If I change the line to simply @item.Category.Name I am running into a Nullreference Exception.

Looking into my database into the device table there are 2 devices listed, with each of those having a CategoryId and ManufactorId in it.

I deemed this a 20 minute no-brainer, but it seems I went terribly wrong somewhere. Please help me solve this error.

If you need additional code, just post it in the comments.

Kind regards

**EDIT:**
In response to those very helpful answers: the error was my faulty controller action.
This solution worked:

```
return View(db.Devices.Include(d => d.Manufactor).Include(d => d.Category).ToList());
```

Comment: How come your selecting var devices but then sending db.Devices to your view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model property is called `Category`, not `Categories,` so make sure you are making the proper `Include`:

```
db.Devices.Include("Category")...
```

Same stands true for the `Manufacturers` of course. Your model property's called `Manufactor` and not `Manufactors` so include the correct one:

```
.Include("Manufactor")
```

Now EF will make proper joins in the tables and hydrate your `Category` and `Manufactor` properties that you could use in your view.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I could cut it down to this line: `return View(db.Devices.Include("Manufactor").Include("Category").ToList());`
I was just looking at my generated database tables and using the names displayed there.

Comment: Yeah, that seems fine. You were scraping the `devices` local variable you selected initially and sent the full data to your view.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Darin's answer: there is also a strong-typed variant of the `Include()` method available which will warn you at compile-time when you use non-existing properties:

```
db.Devices.Include(d => d.Category)
```

Reference: [`DbExtensions.Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx)